# Extending range on SRAM PG-1130 cassette / cassette specification

Tags: shimano, sram, freehub, 1x11

I'm considering buying a Kona Rove ST bike with a 1x drivetrain setup. However, one concern I have is a limited range of higher gears (40:11 ratio for the highest gear). I would like to have some more range there, and would consider replacing the front chainring for a bigger one. Of course that would present a new problem in lower gears.

That could be solved with replacing the whole cassette or installing an expander sprocket, and I prefer the latter because of the costs.

The problem I have is with the specification, or lack thereof, for the SRAM PG-1130 cassette on the Kona. If I understand correctly, it fits a Shimano HG hub standard (?) and differs from the SRAM XG line.

In that case I should be looking at extender cogs designed for Shimano 11 speed cassettes?

Comment: The [Rove ST 2020](https://www.konaworld.com/rove_st.cfm) comes with an 11-42 cassette. Which cassette expander would you buy that is bigger than 42?

Comment: Or that the rear derailleur can deal with

Comment: Wolf Tooth for instance provides a 45T cog designed for Shimano https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/collections/drivetrain-1/products/45t-gc-cog-for-shimano-11-speed

Comment: My 2 cents. If you need a gear bigger than 40x11, then I'm not sure a gravel bike is the right choice. 40x11 at 90 rpm is 25mph or 40kph. Or at least not a 1x gravel bike. Check this site for https://mike-sherman.github.io/shift/ gear/speed/rpm calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRAM PG-1130 cassettes fit on a Shimano HG freehub body, not the SRAM proprietary XD driver body.

If you see `11-42t cassette fits 10 and 11-speed non-XD™ driver bodies` in the description on the SRAM page that means HG.